# Writing a Bash script pulling every word separated by a comma out of a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will read a text file and pull out every word that is followed by a comma on a new line. I tried using `grep` but it prints the whole line that has a comma in it, and I have had the same trouble with `awk`. How to set up this script?

For example if the text file contained a list of animals, like so: " The Veterinary clinic treats the following animals: dogs, cats, and birds" the script would display:

`dogs,
cats,`

Comment: Did you read the man pages for your system's version of grep? does it have a `-o` or `--only-matching` option?

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried it and it only prints the comma.

Comment: So... your expression is only matching the comma: you need to make it match a sequence of word characters followed by a comma

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that, I tried `grep -o '[:alpha:],'` and it outputs just the last letter and the comma, but only for four lines. When I did `grep -o ','` there were 92 commas, so I am very confused.

Comment: `[:alpha:]` means *any single character from the set* `:`,`a`, ... etc. - to match a character from the *POSIX class* `[:alpha:]` you will need `[[:alpha:]]`. You probably also want to match a non-empty sequence of such characters so look at the `+` and/or `{n,m}` modifiers.

Comment: Have you tried `grep -o '.,'` ?

Comment: If it is a CSV file, i.e. only values separated by commas, try `sed 's/,/\n/g' name-of-file`. If you *really* only want the words that are followed by a comma (and not also a newline, as in CSV): `grep -oP '[[:alnum:]]+(?=,)' name of file`

Comment: when I try `grep -oP '[[:alnum:]]+(?=,)' name of file` it prints out grep's usage, and `grep -o '.,'` still just gives me one character before the comma.

Comment: Just to add, I was unaware that the info page went into greater detail than the man page. I was under the impression that they were two ways to get (mostly) the same info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]*,\)/\n\1\n/g' | grep ,
```